# Partial change of home directory in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, partial, home-directory

We are migrating data from one filer to another and we have home directories setup for a bunch of users under their Active Directory profile. Some users have `\\\x.x.x.x\sharename\etc`, some have `\\\hostname\sharename\etc` and some have `\\\hostname.domain.global\sharename\etc`.

I need to replace the first portion of `x.x.x.x`, `hostname` and `hostname.domain.global` with the new DFS name of `domain.global\sharename\etc`, leaving everything else the same.

How can I go about doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: One thing I should mention, every user is unique in that after the \sharename in the example, they have some other folder afterwards so i cannot just change them all to \\\domain.global\sharename\..

Comment: I assume you mean that the new Dfs name is `domain.global` and not `domain.global\sharename\etc`? Please update your question with an example.

Comment: Hello, yes the new DFS name is domain.global, eg.. old:   \\hostname\sharename\etc new   \\domain.global\sharename\etc

Comment: You can use a regular expression (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use regular expressions. Examples:

```
PS C:\> '\\1.2.3.4\sharename1\etc1' |
  Select-String '^\\\\[^\\]+\\(.+)' |
  ForEach-Object { "\\domain.global\{0}" -f $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
\\domain.global\sharename1\etc1

PS C:\> '\\hostname\sharename2\etc2' |
  Select-String '^\\\\[^\\]+\\(.+)' |
  ForEach-Object { "\\domain.global\{0}" -f $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
\\domain.global\sharename2\etc2

PS C:\> '\\hostname.domain.global\sharename3\etc3' |
  Select-String '^\\\\[^\\]+\\(.+)' |
  ForEach-Object { "\\domain.global\{0}" -f $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
\\domain.global\sharename3\etc3
```

The regular expression pattern is:

```
^\\\\[^\\]+\\(.+)
```

This translates to: Start with (`^`) two `\` characters, get 1 or more characters that are not `\`, followed by a single `\`, and then one or more characters (`.+`). The `( )` capture the path portion and make it available in the string replacement (i.e., `$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value`).